# Creating a HTML dropdown menu based on a mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I am attempting to call data from table "aircraft" in database "aircraft"  for a dropdown menu in my html. I'm not even completely sure where to start with it as I don't have experience connecting the two together.

This is what I have for what I want it to look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <select id="nNumber">
   <option value="0">Choose an Aircraft</option>
   <option value="1">N11111 - C172</option>
   <option value="2">N22222 - C172</option>
   <option value="3">N33333 - C172</option>
   <option value="4">N44444 - C172</option>
   <option value="5">N55555 - C172</option>
   <option value="6">N66666 - C172</option>
   <option value="7">N77777 - C172</option>
   <option value="8">N88888 - C172</option>
   <option value="9">N99999 - C172</option>
   <option value="10">N00000 - C172</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

And right now I have table "aircraft" with:

```sql
id int(10) UN AI PK 
N_Number varchar(6) 
Aircraft_Type varchar(15)
```

I would like to be able to sort via Aircraft_Type but have it display like
" 'N_Number' - 'Aircraft_Type' " and have a value of the auto incrementing id number for use with javascript.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There are many many tutorials available online for this kind of thing.

Comment: Start by reading up on how forms work and how to process them in php

Comment: Could someone at least point me in the right direction? I've tried finding the information on how to even get access to the table in html and it just pops up the page with portions of the code displayed in the browser.

Comment: You don't access the table in HTML. HTML is just a markup language which can't connect to anything on it's own . You need to connect to the table using PHP and then output the data using PHP in your HTML. If I were you, I would start by reading a bunch of turorials about "HTML Forms" and then about "PHP + Mysql". The question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
//db connection
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

//query
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM table");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
$select= '<select name="select">';
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>';
  }
}
$select.='</select>';
echo $select;
```